# when opening a new form 2, it shows the settings that i have set

Tags: c#, winforms

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lD9dY.png)

In this section is all of the Form 2 code.Please help me

public void Setting_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

```
        DefaulSetting();
        GetDefaulSetting();
                             
    }

    private void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
```

Button Save Setting

```
public void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{          
    GetDefaulSetting();                      
    MessageBox.Show("Setting save successfully");            
    this.Close();
}
```

radio button

```
    public void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ReportEnable.Checked)
        {
            (this.Owner as Form1).tabControl1.TabPages[4].Enabled = true;             
            ReportDisable.Enabled = true;
            
        }
        else
        {
            ReportDisable.Enabled = true;
            
        }
    }

    public void radioButton1_CheckedChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ReportDisable.Checked)
        {
            (this.Owner as Form1).tabControl1.TabPages[4].Enabled = false;
            ReportEnable.Enabled = true;               
        }
        else
        {
            (this.Owner as Form1).tabControl1.TabPages[4].Enabled = true;
            ReportEnable.Enabled = true;
            
        }
    }

    public void EnableDataTable_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (EnableDataTable.Checked)
        {
            (this.Owner as Form1).tabControl1.TabPages[3].Enabled = true;
            EnableDataTable.Enabled = true;
            
        }
        else
        {                
            EnableDataTable.Enabled = true;
            
        }
    }

    public void DisableDataTable_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (DisableDataTable.Checked)
        {
            (this.Owner as Form1).tabControl1.TabPages[3].Enabled = false;
            DisableDataTable.Enabled = true;
            
        }
        else
        {
            (this.Owner as Form1).tabControl1.TabPages[3].Enabled = true;
            DisableDataTable.Enabled = true;
            
        }
    }

    public void EnableSerialWrite_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (EnableSerialWrite.Checked)
        {
            (this.Owner as Form1).tabControl1.TabPages[1].Enabled = true;
            EnableSerialWrite.Enabled = true;
            
        }
        else
        {
            EnableSerialWrite.Enabled = true;
            
        }
    }

    public void DisableSerialWrite_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (DisableSerialWrite.Checked)
        {
            (this.Owner as Form1).tabControl1.TabPages[1].Enabled = false;
            DisableSerialWrite.Enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            DisableSerialWrite.Enabled = true;
        }
    }

    public void EnableSerialChart_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (EnableSerialChart.Checked)
        {
            (this.Owner as Form1).tabControl1.TabPages[2].Enabled = true;
            (this.Owner as Form1).chart1.Show();
            EnableSerialChart.Enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            EnableSerialChart.Enabled = true;
        }
    }

    public void DisableSerialChart_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (DisableSerialChart.Checked)
        {
            (this.Owner as Form1).tabControl1.TabPages[2].Enabled = false;
            (this.Owner as Form1).chart1.Hide();
            DisableSerialChart.Enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            (this.Owner as Form1).tabControl1.TabPages[2].Enabled = true;
            (this.Owner as Form1).chart1.Show();
            (this.Owner as Form1).chart1.Enabled = true;
            DisableSerialChart.Enabled = true;
        }
    }

    public void EnableSerialRead_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (EnableSerialRead.Checked)
        {
            (this.Owner as Form1).tabControl1.TabPages[0].Enabled = true;
            EnableSerialRead.Enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            EnableSerialRead.Enabled = true;
        }
    }

    public void DisableSerialRead_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (DisableSerialRead.Checked)
        {
            (this.Owner as Form1).tabControl1.TabPages[0].Enabled = false;
            DisableSerialRead.Enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            (this.Owner as Form1).tabControl1.TabPages[0].Enabled = true;
            DisableSerialRead.Enabled = true;
        }
    }

    public void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        EnableSerialChart.Checked = true;
        EnableDataTable.Checked = true;
        EnableSerialRead.Checked = true;
        EnableSerialWrite.Checked = true;
        ReportEnable.Checked = true;
        
    }

    private void Setting_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {           
        
    }

    public void DefaulSetting()
    {
        Settings1.Default.SerialRead = EnableSerialRead.Text;
        Settings1.Default.SerialWrtite = EnableSerialWrite.Text;
        Settings1.Default.SerialChart = EnableSerialChart.Text;
        Settings1.Default.DataTable = EnableDataTable.Text;
        Settings1.Default.Report = ReportEnable.Text;
    }
    public void GetDefaulSetting()
    {           
        EnableSerialRead.Text = Settings1.Default.SerialRead;
        EnableSerialWrite.Text = Settings1.Default.SerialWrtite;
        EnableSerialChart.Text = Settings1.Default.SerialChart;
        EnableDataTable.Text = Settings1.Default.DataTable;
        ReportEnable.Text = Settings1.Default.Report;
        Settings1.Default.Save();
    }
}
```

And this is my form 1 code when hitting the Setting button.

```
public void btnSetting_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Setting frm = new Setting();
            frm.Owner = this;        
            frm.ShowDialog();          
        }
```

Comment: what is your actual question?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details which can be done with a [mre]. Please [edit] your question to add these details into it or we may not be able to help.

Comment: I have set up radio buttons for settings. When I save my settings and when I open Form 2 The buttons I have selected will not appear. How do I set it up, I'm not good at English, sorry.

Comment: I don't see any buttons. All I see is text boxes. When you say "The buttons I have selected will not appear." do you mean you don't see the text boxes, or you can see the text boxes but they are empty? Are you calling GetDefaulSetting in the Setting form load event?

Comment: Is this `EnableSerialRead` one of the RadioButtons?

Comment: Yes, I call DefaulSetting. In the setup form load event But when form 2 is opened, the program will not remember the settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `Settings1.Default.Save();` to the `DefaulSetting` method, call `GetDefaulSetting` in the form load event, and call `DefaulSetting` in the form close event.

You might also consider renaming the methods `ReadSettings` and `WriteSettings` so you don't confuse yourself.

Comment: I can do it, but I have another problem. When I have saved the settings of the button And when opening the settings page again The button will not be selected.

Comment: There's a couple of ways to select a control when a form opens. In this case, I suggest set the tab index of the button to 0.

Comment: I mean the buttons that I have saved. When I open the settings page again Keep the buttons I've selected to show the same.

Comment: That's a totally different question. Did you consider using check boxes instead of radio buttons?